# Mercurial automatic merge

Tags: mercurial, repository, versioning

I'm a newbie in using mercurial and control version system in general,
I know that:

- There exists a Central Remote repository
- Everybody has a local repository, obtained by cloning the central one creating a branch
- Everyone makes changes to a working space area, these changes are then committed  to the local repository.
- After changes have been performed locally, they are merged with the centralized repository or the centralized repository is overwritten by means of a rebasing

In mercurial when we make a pull and two conditions hold:

- the central repository has been changed since we made the last pull.
- we updated our local repository since the last pull.

A merge occurs in the local repository.
Mercurial sometimes wants me to make a manual merge, some other times the merge is managed automatically,I would like to know in what situation this happens.

Comment: What does this have to do with Git. Don't tag it Git if it is about Mercurial.

Comment: Please, avoid opening 2 questions about the same subject, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31772077/236871) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31855996/236871). Keeping all the information in one question would make it more likely for you to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your workflow is just terrible, your mercurial-lingo is dirty
2. Read `hg help merge`

> ... Returns 0 on success, 1 if there are unresolved files

by checking this exit-code you can always know results of (even unattended) merge and perform needed operations.

But **BEWARE**:

> Rebase uses repeated merging to graft changesets from one part of
>   history (the source) onto another (the destination).

thus - if you have exit-code 1 on merge, you, most probably, will get merge-conflict also on rebase (and the need of handwork anyway)

Comment: @GionJh - OK, rewrite your question in order to be more understandable. Use pure, plain, short English sentences like "I have ... I want... I get" so  reader can *understand*, and was not forced to *guess*