# file grained vs line grained version control systems

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, versioning

What are some examples of version control systems that work on files and on lines of files?

In my understanding, a control system that works on file is able to automatically manage merges whenever there are no file conflicts:

for example:

```
A,B,C --> A',B',C
| (branch)  ___________ (merge) -> A',B',C'  
 -------> A,B,C'
```

In what cases a version control system that work on lines is able to manage merge by itself and in what other cases it asks the developer to solve them?

Comment: What???!? where did you get those terms? Never heard of them. A Google search yield nothing.

Comment: Please, avoid opening 2 questions about the same subject, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31772077/236871) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31855996/236871). Keeping all the information in one question would make it more likely for you to get a proper answer.

Comment: I changed the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is too broad/generic but I'll try to give a shot anyways.

Most merge strategies in modern Version Control Systems, can't deal with the following:

Suppose you have files `A` `B` `C` in commit `001` in a repository.
Developer `Dev1` branch of commit `001` and changes one line in file `A`, commits as `001a`.
Developer `Dev2` branch of commit `001` and changes the same line in file `A` and commits as `001b`.

If someone wants to merge commits `001a` and `001b`, the merge system wouldn't be able to tell which is the correct change for the line, maybe the correct change for the project would be using the content in commit `001a` or maybe the one in commit `001b`, or maybe even mix of both changes in the line (that someone would have to create).

That's usually how you get a conflict that need manual intervention, because two developers are working in the same file and line and wrote different changes.

In the rest of the cases the result is obvious:

- No changes in either commit? No changes in the merge result.
- Changes in either of the commits? The change is applied in the merge.
- Changes in the same file but *different lines* (for example, two devs working in different methods)? Both changes are applied in the merge.